# Declaration of container with same type as the class in that class only

Tags: c++, constructor, containers

The following line of code which is a part of file is producing error

```
.\Graph.h:16:3: note: candidate: node::node(int)
   node(int n) : element(n){
   ^~~~
.\Graph.h:16:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
.\Graph.h:10:8: note: candidate: constexpr node::node(const node&)
 struct node{
        ^~~~
.\Graph.h:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
.\Graph.h:10:8: note: candidate: constexpr node::node(node&&)
.\Graph.h:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

The above error typically occurs due to the absence of default constructor as I have researched.

```
struct node{
  int element;
  static vector<bool> check;
  static vector<int> dist;
  static vector<int> f;
  static vector<node> leader;
  node(int n) : element(n){
    if(check.size()<n+1){
      check.resize(n+1);
      leader.resize(n+1);
    }
  }
  bool operator < (node& n){
    if(this->element<n.element)
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
  }
};
```

However, default constructor is not used anywhere else. Also, when I comment out `static vector<node> leader` and other operations related to it, the program doesnt give any error.

So, is the problem because I have declared a container of same type in the same class ?

EDIT - included full error message

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\vector:62:0,
                 from .\Graph.h:5:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = node; _Args = {}]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:519:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = node*; _Size = unsigned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:575:20:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = node*; _Size = unsigned int]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:637:44:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = node*; _Size = unsigned int; _Tp = node]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc:549:35:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = node; _Alloc = std::allocator<node>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:677:21:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = node; _Alloc = std::allocator<node>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]'
.\Graph.h:19:24:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h:75:7: error: no matching function for call to 'node::node()'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.\Graph.h:16:3: note: candidate: node::node(int)
   node(int n) : element(n){
   ^~~~
.\Graph.h:16:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
.\Graph.h:10:8: note: candidate: constexpr node::node(const node&)
 struct node{
        ^~~~
.\Graph.h:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
.\Graph.h:10:8: note: candidate: constexpr node::node(node&&)
.\Graph.h:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\vector:62:0,
                 from .\Graph.h:5:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = node; _Args = {}]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:519:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = node*; _Size = unsigned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:575:20:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = node*; _Size = unsigned int]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:637:44:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = node*; _Size = unsigned int; _Tp = node]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc:549:35:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = node; _Alloc = std::allocator<node>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:677:21:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = node; _Alloc = std::allocator<node>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]'
.\Graph.h:19:24:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h:75:7: error: no matching function for call to 'node::node()'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.\Graph.h:16:3: note: candidate: node::node(int)
   node(int n) : element(n){
   ^~~~
.\Graph.h:16:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
.\Graph.h:10:8: note: candidate: constexpr node::node(const node&)
 struct node{
        ^~~~
.\Graph.h:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
.\Graph.h:10:8: note: candidate: constexpr node::node(node&&)
.\Graph.h:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Next time, please include the full error message. All you posted were the supplementary notes, not the actual error, which would've been along the lines of `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'node'` and a bunch of `std::vector`-internal template instantiation hints. Yes, these errors with more code look scary, but they are there for a reason.

Comment: Aside: your `operator<` can be simplified to `return element < n.element;`

Comment: @MaxLanghof, there were a couple scary lines relating to vectors (none pointed to specific line of code), so I thought it was irrelevant

Comment: @Caleth, thanks for pointing out

Comment: If you wish to have `leader` added to whenever you create a node, you can't have it be a `vector<node>`, as you will be adding copies, and each copy will add to `leader`, and your program continue on until it overflows the stack or fails to reallocate `leader`'s elements

Comment: You *might* be able to have it be a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<node>>`, and `leader.push_back(*this)` in the constructor. But be careful to not have references outlive the `node`s

Comment: @GauravPant But they were relevant, see here: https://godbolt.org/g/rSgo7G - the first one is the problem (cannot construct a `node`), the last three tell you what constructors were available and why they were unusable. The long ones in the middle are indeed a bit noisy, but the next one is the most important one: `in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<node, std::allocator<node> >::resize' requested here:  leader.resize(n+1);`. This directly tells you that the `resize` function is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`leader.resize(n+1);` will resize the vector to have n+1 default constructed `node`s. And so you need a default constructor if you want to have this line.

However without more information with what you expect this vector to be or what to do with it its hard to know how you should fix it.

Note: You can add a default constructor by adding `node() = default;` to your node class.

Comment: So is declaring any container of same type as that of that class allowed ?

Comment: I don't think a defaulted constructor is a good idea here, what would be the correct value for the element member? Perhaps the two-argument resize() is more appropriate

Comment: @gaurav: obviously a node class cannot contain a std::array of 2 nodes, because that would include 4 nodes within those 2 nodes etcetera.

Comment: @GauravPant You can declare a container of instances of the class, but you can't add an instrance to that container each time one is constructed. Because that insertion will then cause another call to the constructor (since it creates a new instance in the container), which will add an element, which will cause another call to the constructor, etc.

Comment: @MSalters, the two argument resize() works (much better solution)

Comment: @GauravPant It's important that you understand that your container will only contain *copies* of the `node`s you create. Changing elements in the container will not have any affect on the `node` you are creating with that constructor and vice-versa.